# Git: merge remote changes

Tags: git

Let's say, I have a branch with my own changes and one commit. But the remote branch is a few commits ahead as well. What is the best way to merge in the remote changes locally, **not to generate merge commits**?

Comment: Why do you not want to generate merge commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rebase ([`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)):

```
git checkout branch
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/branch
```

You will replay your commits on top of the updated remote tracking branch `origin/branch` (replace `branch` by the actual name of the branch)

Even shorter:

```
git pull --rebase origin branch
```

That is valid since you haven't yet pushed '`branch`', and will allow you to resolve any merge issue locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple merge, or you can rebase your changes on the remote branch

L1: local commit

B-C-D Remote commits

```
A--L1
 \
  B--C--D

A--B--C--D--L1
```

do a simple `fetch` and then `rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing a rebase to the remote branch and then pushing.

```
git rebase remote_branch
```

will just put your commit on top of the remote changes.

Then

```
git push
```

will send the changes upstream without any merge commits.